# Terraform aws_dynamodb_table_item - insert multiline JSON into attribute

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I have the following terraform config:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "my_table" {
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.my_table.name
  hash_key   = aws_dynamodb_table.my_table.hash_key

  item = <<ITEM
{
  "id": {"S": "nameAndCodes"},
  "data": {"S": "[
    {
      "code": "03",
      "displayName": "name1"
    },
    {
      "code": "04",
      "displayName": "name2"
    }
  ]"}
}
ITEM
}
```

When the plan stage executes I receive the error:

```
Error: Invalid format of "item": Decoding failed: invalid character '\r' in string literal
```

The only way i can get this to work is to make the whole json a single line as follows:

```
"data": {"S": "[{\"code\": \"03\", \"displayName\": \"name1\"},{\"code\": \"04\", \"displayName\": \"name2\"}]"
```

This looks very ugly and difficult to manage.

Does anyone know how I can enter a multiline JSON inside a <<ITEM block?

Comment: Have you tried `use unix line endings` setting in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve that issue, You can use the `jsonencode` function to set the item value and put entire JSON object in there. Here is an example in Terraform from my project which creates a DynamoDB table and put an initial item.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "customer_table" {
name           = "customer"
billing_mode   = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
hash_key       = "customerId"
stream_enabled = false
attribute {
  name = "customerId"
  type = "S"
 }
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "customer_table_item" {
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.customer_table.name
  hash_key   = aws_dynamodb_table.customer_table.hash_key
  depends_on = [aws_dynamodb_table.customer_table]
  item = jsonencode({
  "customerId" : {
    "S" : "1"
 },
  "firstName" : {
    "S" : "John"
  },
  "lastName" : {
    "S" : "Doe"
  },
})
}
```

commands:
`terrform init`
`terraform fmt`
`terraform plan`
`terraform apply`

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot. Even if your answer is 100% correct, it is super annoying to use your code that you provided.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi - edited above.

Comment: While using `jsonencode` is a good practice you still did not use the example provided, it will still fail

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would recommend you to always do is `terraform validate` that will do a few "simple" checks, makes sure the syntax is valid, and the folder structure is correct if you are using modules, just one quick check before the slower and more complex `terraform plan` stage.

This is not DynamoDB or a Terraform issue, just a syntax issue like the error shows:
`Invalid format ... invalid character '\r' in string literal`
The `\r` is a carriage return character, the end of the line,
if we open quotes you must close them in the same line, we are breaking that simple rule.

Your problem like you find out is on the `data` portion of your item, you are using a string `"S"` that is expected to be in one line but you are splitting it, the one liner is not bad, (I've seen worst) ...
but your better option is to use a proper type for that array field instead of a string.
I would go with using List `"L"` and Maps `"M"`:

Here is a link to all the datatypes available:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes

Your code would look like:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "my_table" {
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.my_table.name
  hash_key   = aws_dynamodb_table.my_table.hash_key

  item = <<ITEM
{
  "id": {"S": "nameAndCodes"},
  "data": {"L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "code": { "S": "03"},
          "displayName": { "S": "name1"}
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "code": { "S": "04"},
          "displayName": { "S": "name2"}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
ITEM
}
```

Then in the AWS console you would get a nice item instead of a string

[image]